# Why can't I save the 'id' on MongoDB using Deno backend?

Tags: database, mongodb, save, deno

I am trying to save the `id` that I get from the MongoDB while saving the stock information as a property of stock using the following code but I get some errors:

```
  async save(stock : Stock) {
    const id  = await stockCollection.insertOne(stock);
    console.log('this is the id: ', id.toString());
    stock.id = id.toString();
    console.log(stock.id);
    // delete stock._id;
    return this;
  }
```

The result of

`console.log('this is the id: ', id.toString());`

is:

```
this is the id:  621e826f90e8bf45a3fe493d
```

And the result of

```
console.log(stock.id);
```

Is also the same:

```
621e826f90e8bf45a3fe493d
```

But when I check the database I see the saved document like below:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"621e7fc2f5b14f28463f289f"},"id":"","open":"2660.7250","high":"2660.7250","low":"2660.5700","close":"2660.5700","volume":"1826"}
```

It seems the line `stock.id = id.toString();` doesn't work and it can not put the `id` into the `id` property of the stock.

Also when I try to remove the `_id` property of the saved stock using this line of the code:

delete stock._id;

It gives me this error:

```
Property '_id' does not exist on type 'Stock'.deno-ts(2339)
```

What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

EDIT: `stock` is an instance of `Stock` class that loads data of a stock using `alpha vantage` library.

stock.ts:

```
import { stockCollection } from "../mongo.ts";
import BaseModel from "./base_model.ts";

export default class Stock extends BaseModel {
  public id: string = "";
  public open: string = "";
  public high: string = "";
  public low: string = "";
  public close: string = "";
  public volume: string = "";


  constructor({ id = "", open = "", high = "", low = "" ,close = "", volume = "" }) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.open = open;
    this.high = high;
    this.low = low;
    this.close = close;
    this.volume = volume;

  }

  static async findOne(params: object): Promise<Stock | null> {
    const stock = await stockCollection.findOne(params);
    if (!stock) {
      console.log('there is no stock');
      return null;
    }
    console.log('there is a stock');

    return new Stock(Stock.prepare(stock));
  }

  async save(stock : Stock) {
    const id  = await stockCollection.insertOne(stock);
    console.log('this is the id: ', id.toString());
    stock.id = id.toString();
    console.log(stock.id);
    // delete stock._id;
    return this;
  }
}
```

BaseModel.ts:

```
export default class BaseModel {
  public static prepare(data: any) {
    data.id = data._id.toString();
    // delete data._id;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here I am trying to save one instance of a stock in database:

```
export const stockSave = async () => {
  const YOUR_API_KEY = '***********';
  const alpha = new AlaphaVantage('***********');
  const writestock = await alpha.stocks.intraday('GOOG' , '1min' ).then((data: any) => {return data["Time Series (1min)"]["2022-02-28 14:31:00"]} );
  console.log('this is writestock' , writestock);
  const stock = new Stock({
   id:  "",
   open:  writestock["1. open"],
   high:  writestock["2. high"],
   low: writestock["3. low"],
   close: writestock["4. close"],
   volume:  writestock["5. volume"]});
  await stock.save(stock);
}
```

Edit2: This is the whole project code: https://github.com/learner00000/back

Comment: What is `Stock`? Which MongoDB module are you using? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't instantiate each instance of `Stock` with an actual ID, and you are instead relying on the ID to be generated by MongoDB, you should not store the `id` property in the database. You'll probably need to update your schema to reflect this.

You haven't shown a reproducible example with all of the imports and data, so I'm left to guess a bit about some types, but you can refactor the relevant parts of the class like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=41&ssc=2&pln=4&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3ppYDWAwkhBOBgJaoBc8A3vOeiDBgPIoIAUADrFALY0oKAJ4BKGgAUYSfuTQgAPPQxIAyhhiMA5pwnZNO+AF8AfAG4TAKFCRYCO2jTwAQlAUBZJKAh1j5qytkdCwcfAARKAwoAGkQEWcAXngAbQBySCQFNIAaeDSAC3JtAtz8iCQAdzK0pG4QFBqAN2IAV34QNIBdeHdEVEwAjBF6+A1cPEjouJF4ZOH6pAAzAwmp2Pi0FJR2gCNmLqGRhHGIqKg5+AAlcCQYYEVTyfOZvMwtFG0LQMdnJ-gQAAPDANYDONyebwgXzkfjcUgdFAYP6qM7ROhWeDwbitXYQchgBjAGjvHQBLE4vEExAVBQkwyfcnY3H4wlFEr0j7aJmU1nwCqVTlkzHMqmEuoNIWMkW86ktCDtEBS7mBLHBd6tMCqGDwTiMcgYKSwChQCCPVHPdEAMjoROVljMl1oxjEGKxWLQrXqMD0TKxGCKaAAdORgJd9RgQ2GAPzR-JpP3wAPyIOZBThlAG1O0hCx+OJ5PB9kFDNZ4vwPNpBMi-2BoMC0uRhuV6vupN1iUoRtBzsVuNVgt1+WK7vDjp9-Mi4yq+DaEAYda6-RPRe0Gv9ELwYDnJ3GXootbnRNLO669VYPDxeDLVZojYJV3b6IpS8iHrzQMv+KHddwDCtGAuyfKAmWnEUCncABJMM9BoXYkGIEBhDdd0-wArsXAQ0hhE4QsozEUCZ3cEQUEJNAoCaLh9GkWR5CUFpQ1MFC1QGLBgMuPC5wXc5fXXc8iSxZIoEqKADVvQhiFILVKBQEMmBYdgQE4YCCPXPDQ3DYAg1UDQuV4rFp2nIA)

```ts
const stockDataKeys = ['close', 'high', 'low', 'open', 'volume'] as const;
type StockDataKey = typeof stockDataKeys[number];
type StockData = Record<StockDataKey, string>;

class Stock extends BaseModel implements StockData {
  public id: string;
  public close: string;
  public high: string;
  public low: string;
  public open: string;
  public volume: string;

  constructor (init: Partial<StockData & { id: string; }> = {}) {
    super();
    this.id = init.id ?? '';
    this.close = init.close ?? '';
    this.high = init.high ?? '';
    this.low = init.low ?? '';
    this.open = init.open ?? '';
    this.volume = init.volume ?? '';
  }

  getData (): StockData {
    const data = {} as StockData;
    for (const key of stockDataKeys) data[key] = this[key];
    return data;
  }

  hasId (): boolean {
    return Boolean(this.id);
  }

  async save (): Promise<void> {
    const data = this.getData();
    const id  = await stockCollection.insertOne(data);
    this.id = id.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I also added the complete project code to the Edit2 part of the question.

Comment: I tried to modify my code using your suggestions but I get this error code: `error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1. open')
   open:  writestock["1. open"],`

Comment: @WDR Without reproduction steps to follow and all the data needed to reproduce your error, I am unable to respond to your comment in a way that would be useful to you. If you need help with debugging an error, it is important that you provide **everything** needed to enable another person to reproduce the error exactly as you saw it.

Comment: I uploaded the full project code(although it is a small project) on Github and put the link on `Edit2`(last line) of my question.